# Oracle REGEXP confusion

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

Question: Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

Solution I tried but failed (giving incorrect output):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(city, '^(a|e|i|o|u).*(a|e|i|o|u)$','i');
```

Solution which worked:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(city, ^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$,'i');
```

Please can anyone explain why the first solution is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version logically says to *not* find cities which begin *and* end with vowels.  However, it leaves open the possibility for a city which starts with a vowel, but does not end with a vowel.  It also admits cities which do not start with a vowel, but end with a vowel.  The second version only allows cities which start and end with no vowel letters.

As a side note, the regex in your first version would better be written as:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(city, '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$', 'i');
```

That is, use the character class in square brackets rather than an alternation of single letters (though your alternation was correct, just slightly awkward).

Comment: -Got the awkward code part.
-Understood the logic which you explained regarding my first code
-Can you explain how I can fix my first code only for the required result, instead of using the second code, just out of curiosity.

Comment: Or as an alternative - faster `substr` instead of regex: `not( substr(city, 1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') or substr(city, -1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'))`, which also allows a name to be of one letter (though, it doesn't look like real name, but should pass the test in case of different semantics with the same filter requirement).

Answer (score 2):

> Can you explain how I can fix my first code only for the required result, instead of using the second code, just out of curiosity.

In boolean logic `(NOT A AND NOT B) = NOT (A OR B)` so if is `A` is "starts with a vowel" and `B` is "ends with a vowel" then you want to find the values where it does not either start or end with a vowel:

Which could be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE  NOT (  REGEXP_LIKE(city, '^(a|e|i|o|u)','i')
           OR REGEXP_LIKE(city, '(a|e|i|o|u)$','i') );
```

or, as a single regular expression:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(city, '^(a|e|i|o|u)|(a|e|i|o|u)$','i');
```

*Note: you can replace `(a|e|i|o|u)` with `[aeiou]`.*